# Formatting Text in Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, font, formatting

I'd like to have all email that I send formatted with my font and size and color, like the way web based email does it. I'd just like to set a default font and have all email I send formatted this way. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: What version of Mail.app are you using (there are different versions for OS 10.6 and 10.7)?

Comment: OS Lion latest Version (10.7.3?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail doesn't offer the feature you want (except via the "stationery" option).  People who find it essential usually move to Thunderbird or Entourage/Outlook.  There are, however, a couple apps aimed at adding this, like Message Font

http://messagefont.com/

Comment: That's pretty cool. I like how it has an iOS app. Can it set account specific Signatures in the iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

You should go into Mail preferences > Composing tab and choose to send "Rich Text" mail.

Comment: Thats enabled by default. I'm trying to set the default styles